# PDF/PMF of the number of people between two friends in a line with 8 others (10 people total)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be the number of people in between friends A and B placed randomly in a line of 8 others.

There are ${10\choose2}$ total arrangements with two friends and the number of people between them.

There are $9 - X$ arrangements with X amount of people in between friends A and B.

Therefore the pdf is $p_X(x) = \frac{9 - x}{10\choose2}, $ for $x\in {0, ..., 8}$ 0 otherwise.

Don't know if this is correct, or if I am over/under counting.

Answer (score 1):

I think your work is fine. Here is an alternate approach.

There are $10!$ ways to order $10$ people in a line.
There are $2(9-x)$ ways to position $A$ and $B$ so that there are $x$ people between them. There are $8!$ ways to order the remaining $8$ people into the remaining positions. This yields
$$\frac{2(9-x)8!}{10!} = \frac{9-x}{\frac{10!}{8!2}} = \frac{9-x}{\binom{10}{2}}.$$

Comment: Yes that was my first approach but then I realized that the other multipliers cancel out. There are $2!(9 - x)$ ways to position $A$ and $B$.